# Скрытие других элементов по нажатию на элемент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется скрипт:

```
$(".item").each(function() {
    var a = $(this).find("a");
    var text = $(this).find(".dnone");
    var preview = $(this).find(".preview");
    $(a).click(function() {
        $(preview).toggleClass("dnone");
        $(text).toggleClass("dnone");
        return false;
    });
});
```

И имеется список из 10 элементов `.item`. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии одного из `var a` остальные все скрывались (как в аккордеоне)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предположить, что под размытой фразой "остальные все скрывались" на самом деле имеется в виду "добавить класс `dnone` всем другим `text` и убрать класс `dnone` у всех других `preview`", то в рамках текущего кода это можно сделать так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $items = $('.item');
    var $previews = $items.find('.preview');
    var $texts = $items.find('.dnone');
    $items.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $a = $this.find("a");
        var $text = $this.find(".dnone");
        var $preview = $this.find(".preview");
        $a.on("click", function() {
            $previews.not($preview).removeClass("dnone");
            $texts.not($text).addClass("dnone");
            $preview.toggleClass("dnone");
            $text.toggleClass("dnone");
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.item {
    margin: 15px;
}
.dnone {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <a href="">link1</a>
    <div class="preview">preview1</div>
    <div class="dnone">text1</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a href="">link2</a>
    <div class="preview">preview2</div>
    <div class="dnone">text2</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a href="">link3</a>
    <div class="preview">preview3</div>
    <div class="dnone">text3</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

В вопросе отсутствуют HTML и CSS, но схематичный пример таков.

Использование класса `dnone` для выборки `text` не является логичным, поэтому имеет смысл всем `text` добавить класс `text` и выбирать их по этому классу, оставив классу `dnone` лишь функцию скрытия элементов.

Также имеет смысл добавить всем `a` какой-то класс (например, `link`), чтобы делать выборку по классу, а не по тегу - это является более гибким решением.